# What is the map projection for FAA terminal procedure charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

What is the map projection for FAA terminal procedure charts and what are the parameters (standard parallels) for each specific airport? I couldn’t find any information with the publication information and also not on the charts.

Comment: Most terminal procedure charts are not even to scale: "Generally, DP charts are depicted “not to scale” due to the great distances involved on some procedures or route segments." ([Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide - Terminal Procedure Publications](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/cug-tpp-edition.pdf)). In those cases, the map projection does not matter since the charts are more of a sketch anyway. I don't know what they use when the charts are to scale though.

Comment: @Bianfable You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @TomMcW Well, it doesn't really answer the question. Some charts are to scale and that means they must have a map projection. The document I found does not say which one they use...

Comment: Thank you @Bianfable, while this applies to most STARs and SIDs I guess, the IAPs should be to scale (and a projection?), as they are georeferenced when used in e.g. ForeFlight.

Comment: @TobiBS What do you mean by “they are geofeferenced?”

Comment: It means some applications like ForeFlight can display the chart overlayed on the moving map. The G1000 can do that do too, I think.

Comment: If it’s capable of doing that And the points line up properly then there are two possibilities: either the charts use the same projection as the moving map uses or at that scale there isn’t a significant difference. I would expect the latter.